# How to create group values in classes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with a column:

```
pb['Progress']
```

whose type is object and values are:

```
Choose Product
Account Access
Credit Profile
Ineligible
Declined (Credit | Internal)
Approved (Underwritten)
Declined (ID & Bank)
E-Sign (Accepted)
Declined (Underwritten)
Unauthorised
Pre-Declined
Initial Payment
E-Sign (Referred)
Approved (Automatic)
Referred (Automatic | Expired)
```

I'd like to add one more column to the df such that

```
Approved (Underwritten)
Approved (Automatic)
E-Sign (Accepted)
Initial Payment
```

will be get label 1 and the rest label 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pb['label'] = pb['Progress']

pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Approved (Underwritten)', '1')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Approved (Automatic)', '1')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('E-Sign (Accepted)', '1')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Initial Payment', '1')

pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Choose Product', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Account Access', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Credit Profile', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Ineligible', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Declined (Credit | Internal)', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Declined (ID & Bank)', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Declined (Underwritten)', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Unauthorised', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Pre-Declined', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('E-Sign (Referred)', '0')
pb['label'] = pb['label'].replace('Referred (Automatic | Expired)', '0')
```